# Kill shell script after X seconds

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script thats running a docker container. I want the shell script to kill the container if it runs longer than x seconds.

How would I monitor the time in the shell script to kill it if the time the script has been running exceeds x seconds?

Answer (score 4):

You could just use timeout.

```
timeout 10 ping 1.1.1.1
```

It kills the process after 10s.

Comment: See the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section in [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), particularly the bullet point regarding questions which "...have already been asked and answered many times before".

Comment: Also note that -- as described in [BashFAQ #68](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/068) -- `timeout` is not built into bash, and thus not guaranteed to be available (or behave consistently -- there are at least four distinct known implementations)  everywhere bash is installed.